# How to use Pod yaml file in Jenkins to create container

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kaniko

I use a POD yaml file to create a pod in Kubernetes.

My yaml file is simple and looks like this:

```
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - /busybox/cat
    tty: true
```

but I got this Error message:

```
nodes are available: 33 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

I run this pod file in Jenkins pipeline, so that a Kaniko can be installed to build a docker image.

any solutions?

Comment: is this full yaml file or there other config like node selector ?

Comment: this is full yaml file

Answer (score 1):

You are missing several required keys in your YAML file.

1. `apiVersion` key - api version for Pod is currently `v1`
2. `metadata` key - Data that helps uniquely identify the object, including a `name` string, `UID`, and optional `namespace`

You can read more on creating static pods in Kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/), and if you want some examples for kaniko pod, they are available [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/tree/master/examples).

So, minimal correct pod YAML should looke like this:

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  # specify your pod name
  name: <pod-name>
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - /busybox/cat
    tty: true
```

Addressing the problem:
You can assign which pod should run on which node with use of the `nodeSelector` key. You need to specify it under `spec`. For example:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - /busybox/cat
    tty: true
  #here it is
  nodeSelector:
    # and here is node label
    <label-name>: <label-value>
```

You can find your node labels with

```
kubectl describe node <node-name>
```

or add a label to it with

```
kubectl label node <node-name> <label-name>=<label-value>
```

You can find more on this in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this as an example:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: worker
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    command: ["/busybox/cat"]
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: dockercred
        mountPath: /root/.docker/
  volumes:
  - name: dockercred
    secret:
      secretName: dockercred
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1: Build with Kaniko') {
      steps {
        container('kaniko') {
          sh '/kaniko/executor --context=git://github.com/repository/project.git \
                  --destination=repository/image:tag \
                  --insecure \
                  --skip-tls-verify  \
                  -v=debug'
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

The `secret` I mount is the docker credentials to be used by Kaniko.